# Changing Razor View Seems to Restart My Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It appears to me that a simple change to a .cshmtl file in my application restarts the application. Honestly I'm not sure it's restarting, but it is painfully slow when I am reloading the page. Does this seem normal? Anyone have any advice to figure out why this might be happening? It makes development a real drag.

I feel like I have time to get up and get a cup of coffee and a cigarette every time I make a change. And I don't even smoke! If this continues, I might have to take up smoking.

Comment: Does this happen if you create a brand new application or is it only in your application?

Comment: use firebug or chrome developer tools to monitor the page loading to  see if it is hanging

Comment: It seems to only happen with this one application. I know we are using Squish it for some things (squishing files and compiling coffeescript)-- I was thinking that might be the issue ?? Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your `View` the Application should not restart. But it takes some time cause your `View` gets compiled before rendered.

You can set a breakpoint on the `Application_Start()` method in global.asax to see if your Application gets restarted.

Answer (score -1):

There are so many threads related to Session loss, Cache loss and Application restart.  The reason for all of these is that IIS [and yes IISExpress] will restart the app pool when anything in the BIN folder changes.  MVC will compile the Razor views of an application on demand.  This view compilation will update the BIN folder.  The update to the BIN folder will reset the app pool.  This clears session and clears cache, and call Application_End.